# How do I make buttons the same size

Tags: css

I'm trying to get buttons that are all the same size, however I'm new and therefore stuck, here's my CSS code :

```
.bannerArea nav ul li{
    list-style:none;    
    display:inline;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    opacity:0.7;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:none;
}
```

http://www.webpagetemplates.org/web-page-templates/download/preview/wpt0054/
Notice the buttons ? They are all the same size, like I want. And also, how do I center the actual buttons and not just the text?

Answer (score 1):

Top tip: putting a test case into a JSFiddle will give people a clearer idea of your problem, and thus provide you with an answer.

Having said that, you want to use `display: block` instead of `inline` and then set a width:

```
.bannerArea nav ul li{
    list-style:none;    
    display:block;
    width: 25%; /* Adjust this accodringly */
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    opacity:0.7;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:none;
```

}

Comment: Hi thanks alot, and yes I'm kinda new to stackoverflow and html etc. Is it possible to have these buttons horizontal instead of vertical ? TYVM in advance, you've already been a good help

Comment: Yes, add `float: left` to the above set of rules. You might also need to add:

    `.bannerArea nav ul {
        clear: both;
    }`

Comment: If that answer worked for you mark it as correct so that this question can be closed.